# How can I determine the version of a MAT file from MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, mat-file

I am wondering if there is a way to determine whether a particular MAT file is v4, v6, v7 or v7.3?

I am looking for a solution that can determine the version using MATLAB code, preferably without having to load the data into memory.

Comment: There is a comment at the beginning of each file, use `type` to display it. It says `5.0` for v6 and v7, not sure what happened.

Comment: @Daniel That's very useful - I had no idea. You should put that as an answer, would upvote.

Comment: Just to add to @Daniel 's comment, `v4` files seem to have no comment header, `v6` and `v7` files have a header saying 5.0, and `v7.3` files have a header saying 7.3.

Comment: @Daniel is there anyway to capture the first few lines of the output of "type" in a variable? That could help as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is some comment at the beginning of mat-files version 6 or following. This code reads it:

```
function txt=getMatComment(x)
fid=fopen(x);
txt=char(fread(fid,[1,140],'*char'));
txt=[txt,0];
txt=txt(1:find(txt==0,1,'first')-1);
end
```

It seems the comment is always 116 chars long, but I did not find any reference. This code reads 140 chars and cuts of at the end.

The part I don't understand: For Version 6 or 7 it says `MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file`

Comment: For your last question, I think that the answer lies in the second column of the table: https://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/mat-file-versions.html

Comment: More precisely, the correspondence between the output from `getMatComment` and file version is given in MATLAB preferences (General/MAT-files), see screenshot below from R2019b